# Chinese Remainder Theorem whose modulus are not coprime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Is it possible to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem to the follow system of congruences?
$$\begin{align}x&\equiv1\mod 15\\
x&\equiv2\mod 21\\ 
x&\equiv3 \mod 35\end{align}$$ 
$15, 21$ aren't coprime
$21$ and $35$ aren't coprime
Is CRT applicable to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

$$x \equiv 1 \pmod{15} \iff
   \begin{array}{c}
      x \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\ x \equiv 1 \pmod 5
   \end{array} $$

$$x \equiv 2 \pmod{21} \iff
   \begin{array}{c}
      x \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \\ x \equiv 2 \pmod 7
   \end{array} $$

$$x \equiv 3 \pmod{35} \iff
   \begin{array}{c}
      x \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \\ x \equiv 3 \pmod 7
   \end{array} $$

Note that there are contradictions with the values of
$x \pmod 3, x \pmod 5, \ \text{and} \ x \pmod 7$.

Hence there can be no solution.

Answer (score 1):

The system doesn't have a solution, You can apply CRT to $x \equiv 1 \bmod 15$ to get $x \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $x \equiv 1 \bmod 5$, and since $5$ and $21$ are coprime, you can combine $x \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ and $x \equiv 2 \bmod 21$ to get $x \equiv 86 \bmod 105$, which is incompatible with $x \equiv 3 \bmod 35$.

Comment: Isnt it simpler ? $3$ divides $15$ and $21$ so $1\equiv 2(\mod 3)$.

Comment: Is there a quick way to see if a system does not have a solution? Do I just check to see if the modulus are coprime or not?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus that is a faster method, you're right

Comment: @Juan systems with non-coprime moduli can have solutions, but they don't have to. For example, $x \equiv 2 \bmod 4, x \equiv 4 \bmod 6$ has a solution, but not (say) $x \equiv 2 \bmod 4, x \equiv 3 \bmod 6$. The simple method is to apply CRT to break every congruence into a system of congruences modulo powers of primes, and then check whether the resulting system is inconsistent.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by inconsistent?

Comment: For an example, in the system that you posed, $x \equiv 1 \bmod 15$ implies $x \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $x \equiv 2 \bmod 21$ implies $x \equiv 2 \bmod 3$, and this is inconsistent (i.e., doesn't have a solution).